# want to post on Friends wall on using blackberry Facebook Sdk

Tags: facebook, blackberry, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate my application to Facebook. I download the [Facebook BB Sdk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/files/) and Now I can post on user's wall using

```
user.publishStatus("Hello world")
```

I the read me of this sdk says
 To post to the user’s friends’ walls:

```
User[] friends = user.getFriends(); 

if (friends != null && friends.length > 0) { 
  for (int i=0; i<friends.length; i++) {     
friends[i].publishPost(post); 
    } 
}
```

But user.getFriends() returns a type `Profile` and there is no method like `publishPost()`

**My question is**

How can i post friend's wall from using sdk ? please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download graph api from http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/. After that you have to add two thinks.

one is when you want to post a photo to your friends wall ,you have to put one more key-value in the JSONObject(Request) - that is requestObject.put("target_id",getid()) in publisePhoto method facebookuser.java & facebook.java

Second is you have to change JSONObject responseObject = fb.write(getId() + "/photos", requestObject, pPhoto.getMIMEType(), imageData, true);

to

JSONObject responseObject = fb.write(getId() + "/photos?access_token="+Facebook.token, requestObject, pPhoto.getMIMEType(), imageData, true);in FacebookUser.java & Facebook.java

where token is Static string from Facebook.java and store the value of access_token (you have to add it)

Comment: Thank you for your Response. in fb.write() there are three arguments. write(path,JsonObject,retry) . for posting friends wall what value given to path , what is the value of the jsonobject, please help me.. thank you